# Is there a way to configure the polling interval of UPower?

Tags: power-management, battery

On Ubuntu 18.04, Upower 0.99.7 polls battery status every 2 minutes.  Is there a way to configure the polling interval, e.g., 10 seconds?  I couldn't find any in /etc/Upower/Upower.conf file.

If Upower devs are listening, then it would be great if users can associate aggressive and relaxed polling intervals.  For example, 10 seconds when battery% < 30% (or time left < 30 mins) and 120 seconds interval when battery% >= 30% (time left >= 30 mins).